# How do I add multiple input values into an array if some of the values are dynamically created?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an object that looks like this

```
    const [combat, setCombat] = useState({
        ac:'',
        proBonus:'',
        init:'',
        speed:'',
        atkPerRound:'',
        resistances:[]
    })
```

i also have a series of inputs that add their values to the respective key. one of the inputs is called `resist` and it has a button that makes a new input also called `resist`. its supposed to add the value of each input to the array in `combat.resistances` so the array will look like this

```
    const [combat, setCombat] = useState({
        ac:'',
        proBonus:'',
        init:'',
        speed:'',
        atkPerRound:'',
        resistances:['resistInputValue', 'resistInputValueFromDynamicInput']
    })
```

but when i try to add a value to dynamically created inputs i get this error
`e.preventDefault is not a function TypeError: e.preventDefault is not a function`
the function that adds the new input looks like this

```
    const handleAdd = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()

        const newResistList = document.getElementById('newResistList')

        const newResist = document.createElement('input')
        newResist.type = 'text'
        newResist.placeholder = 'Resistance'
        newResist.name = 'resist'

        newResist.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
            handleChange(e, {target: {value: e.target.value}})
        })

        newResistList.appendChild(newResist)
    }
```

and the function that adds the values to `combat` looks like this

````
    const handleChange = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()

        if(e.target.name === 'resist'){
            setCombat({...combat, resistances: [e.target.value]})
        }else{
            setCombat({...combat, [e.target.name]: e.target.value})
        }
    }```


heres the `resist` input itself
````

```
        <p id='resistList'>
            <label htmlFor='resist'>Resistances</label>
            <input name='resist' type='text' onChange={handleChange} placeholder='Resistances'/>
            <span id='newResistList'></span>
            <button name='addButton' onClick={handleAdd}>Add Resistance</button>
        </p>
```

```
ive tried ending the `handleChange` function with `return false` and starting it with `stopPropogation`(ive heard that could work as a workaround to `preventDefault` not working) but it throws a `e.stopPropagation is not a function`. 

making it `return false` keeps it from reloading, but now my `handleChange` function throws a `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')` error.

so, i just logged `e.target` at the top of the `handleChange` function, and in new inputs its `undefined`, but when i log `newResist` at the bottom of the `handleAdd` function it logs properly.
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your question. However it seems like you are not familiar with the guide of Stack Overflow to [How To: Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please read it and adjust your question accordingly by using the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77068047/edit) option. Happy coding!

Comment: Please provide more details or a sample. It's not clear what exactly you're asking. With that being said, the code you've written is not really React code. The general idea of React (and all the other frameworks out there) is being declarative (Defining what the DOM should look like in a certain state) instead of being imperative (Defining step-by-step how an DOM update is made using `document.createElement()` etc). Please go back to a React tutorial and have a look on how you would do something like this in general. You are completely on the wrong track here.

Comment: You can't pass combat.resistances.length into handleChange like that.  As is, handleChange expects the first parameter to be an event, but it's getting a number instead and causing errors like e.stopPropagation is not a function

Answer (score 0):

okay, so i changed alot of the logic, but it works now.

in the `handleAdd` function i just made it add an empty string to the resistances array then i used `.map()` to make a new text input for each string in the array. heres the changed code

```
    const newResist = document.createElement('input')
var resistCount = 1
const handleAdd = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()

    setCombat((prevCombat) => ({
        ...prevCombat,
        resistances: [...prevCombat.resistances, '']
    }))
}
```

hen, i had to make a special function just for updating the values in the `resistances` array.

```
    const handleResistChange = (i, value) => {

    setCombat((prevCombat) => {
        const updatedResistances = [...prevCombat.resistances]
        updatedResistances[i] = value
        return {...prevCombat, resistances: updatedResistances}
    })

    return false
}
```

after that i just needed to use my existing logic on all the other inputs to fill out the rest of the object

```
    const handleChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()

    setCombat({...combat, [e.target.name]: e.target.value})
}
```

shoutout to Mushroomator for pointing me in the right direction as far as terminology and james for pointing out an admittedly obvious flaw in the code. im still learning and not always sure where to look for answers or even what to ask